# Check if value in list within dictionary value dict and return index

Tags: python, dictionary

Assuming that I have a dictionary with str keys and dicts as values:

```
{'one': {1: (3, [0.001, 0.003]), 2: (13, [0.005, 0.007]), 0: (4, [0.008, 0.008])}, 
'two': {0: (12, [0.01, 0.016]), 1: (6, [0.03, 0.036]), 2: (1, [0.04, 0.04])}}
```

How can I check if the value 0.0015 is in the range of each list of values within the nested dict, i.e. [0.001, 0.003], [0.005, 0.007] etc.) and if it is, to return 'one' or 'two' and the index of the value for the key 'one' or 'two'?

For the above example of 0.0015, I would like to return ['one', 0] because this value is between 0.001 and 0.003 and this range [0.001, 0.003] is the first one in terms of position from left to right.

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Comment: A simple for loop with the `dict.items()` function should suffice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give it a try:

```
d = {'one': {1: (3, [0.001, 0.003]), 2: (13, [0.005, 0.007]), 0: (4, [0.008, 0.008])},
     'two': {0: (12, [0.01, 0.016]), 1: (6, [0.03, 0.036]), 2: (1, [0.04, 0.04])}}

VAL = 0.0015
for k, v in d.items():
    for idx, (k1, v1) in enumerate(v.items()):
        pair = v1[1]
        if pair[0] <= VAL <= pair[1]:
            print(f'{k} {idx}')
```

output

```
one 0
```